# Installing anything in ubuntu then showing always security issue related error

Tags: ubuntu, security, http-status-code-404

Here this result is of when i was installing pip in my system

i----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------i

```
      xc@xc:~$ sudo apt install python3-pip
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      libexpat1-dev libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libpython3-dev libpython3.9-dev
      python-pip-whl python3-dev python3-distutils python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.9-dev
      zlib1g-dev
    Suggested packages:
      python-setuptools-doc
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      libexpat1-dev libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libpython3-dev libpython3.9-dev
      python-pip-whl python3-dev python3-distutils python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel
      python3.9-dev zlib1g-dev
    0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
    Need to get 8,653 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 29.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
      libjs-jquery libjs-underscore libjs-sphinxdoc libpython3-dev python-pip-whl python3-distutils
      python3-dev python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-pip
    Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
```

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 libexpat1-dev amd64 2.4.1-2ubuntu0.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
Ign:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libjs-jquery all 3.5.1+dfsg+~3.5.5-7 
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 zlib1g-dev amd64 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu7.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
Ign:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libjs-underscore all 1.9.1~dfsg-3
Ign:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libjs-sphinxdoc all 3.5.4-2
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 libpython3.9-dev amd64 3.9.7-2ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 python3.9-dev amd64 3.9.7-2ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
Err:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libpython3-dev amd64 3.9.4-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Ign:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 python-pip-whl all 20.3.4-4
Ign:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 python3-distutils all 3.9.7-1
Err:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 python3-dev amd64 3.9.4-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Ign:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 python3-setuptools all 52.0.0-4
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 python3-wheel all 0.34.2-1 [23.8 kB]
Ign:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 python3-pip all 20.3.4-4
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libjs-jquery all 3.5.1+dfsg+~3.5.5-7
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libjs-underscore all 1.9.1~dfsg-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 libjs-sphinxdoc all 3.5.4-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Err:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 python-pip-whl all 20.3.4-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Err:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 python3-distutils all 3.9.7-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Err:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 python3-setuptools all 52.0.0-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Err:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 python3-pip all 20.3.4-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Fetched 23.8 kB in 3s (8,811 B/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/expat/libexpat1-dev_2.4.1-2ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/node-jquery/libjs-jquery_3.5.1%2bdfsg%2b%7e3.5.5-7_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/underscore/libjs-underscore_1.9.1%7edfsg-3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sphinx/libjs-sphinxdoc_3.5.4-2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g-dev_1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu7.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.9/libpython3.9-dev_3.9.7-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/libpython3-dev_3.9.4-1build1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python-pip-whl_20.3.4-4_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.9/python3.9-dev_3.9.7-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-stdlib-extensions/python3-distutils_3.9.7-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-dev_3.9.4-1build1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/setuptools/python3-setuptools_52.0.0-4_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python3-pip_20.3.4-4_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First try this two commands `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and try to install what do you want `sudo apt-get install (package name)`.

Comment: ``Ign:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease  
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
Ign:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Err:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release
``

Comment: still getting error

Comment: my ubuntu version was outdated so this was happening , upgrading ubuntu to 22.04 version fixed all of my issue